# tensorflowのeval()について

Tags: python, tensorflow

画像に対するCNNのプログラムを勉強中で，`model`関数で畳み込みを行うのですが、`pred`を

```
result = self.pred.eval({self.images: train_data, self.labels: train_label})
```

で走らせています．この`eval()`は`model`関数に`train_data`と`train_label`の画像データを渡していると思うのですが，`model`関数では畳み込みに`self.images`の`train_data`しか使用していません．なぜ、`train_label`も渡しているのでしょうか．

ここでの処理は、一通りトレーニングを終えて、サンプル画像を用いてどのくらいの精度かテストしている処理です。
`tranin_data`はトレーニングデータで、`train_label`は正解データを別の関数でデータセットとして作成しています．

```
def train(self, config):
    train_data, train_label = read_data(data_dir)
    self.train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(config.learning_rate).minimize(self.mse)

    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    self.pred = model()


def model(self):
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(self.images, self.weights['w1'], strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='VALID') + self.biases['b1'])
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(conv1, self.weights['w2'], strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='VALID') + self.biases['b2'])
    conv3 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv2, self.weights['w3'], strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='VALID') + self.biases['b3']
    return conv3
```

Answer (score 1):

> なぜ、train_labelも渡しているのでしょうか．

eval(evaluate)関数は、モデルの精度をはかる関数ですから、データとその正解レベルを与えないといけないのは当たり前ですよね。正解を与えなければ、モデルがその問題を当てたのかどうか判断できませんから。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。self.predをeval()で実行させているということは、model()を実行させているのではないのでしょうか。model()では、self.images:train_dataしか使われていないので、どのような処理過程でself.labels: train_labelが使われているのかが疑問です。

Comment: まず、そもそも、コードが提示されないことには、こちらは推測することしかできません。その問いに答えられるのはあなたしかいません。すくない状況から推測して、あなたの観測の方が間違っている可能性の方が高い、といわざるをえないです。逆に聞きますが「train_labelを使わずに精度を計算する方法が存在する」と思っているのですか?

Comment: model()の実行結果がself.predに代入されていて、selef.pred.eval(...)が呼び出されているんですから、「model()の実行結果が返すオブジェクト」がevalというメソッドを持っているはずです。そしてそれはTesorflowの精度計算用の計算グラフを起動するように書いているはずです。（提示されたソースから推測したことでしかないですが）その計算グラフの定義を追ってください。